# Php Static Class and Normal Class

Tags: php, function, class, static

```
$export = db::get($data);

foreach ($export as $user) {
    //
}

echo "Totol User: " . $export->count();
```

Hello, I have a problem.
I'm pulling array() with db::get($data). Then I want to show the total number of records with a function such as $export->count().

Is there an example suitable for this structure? Can you help me?

Comment: [`count()` in the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.count.php).

Comment: Probably overkill, but you could return an `ArrayObject` from `get()` or do `$export = new ArrayObject(db::get($data));` and then `$export->count;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much to it, but there seems to be a misunderstanding about what an array can do.

An array in PHP is not an object with methods like `->count()`. It has no methods or properties.

Instead you pass the array as an argument to the built-in PHP function `count()`.

```
echo "Totol User: " . count($export);
```

---

The `sizeof()` function is an alias of `count()`. They are interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sizeof():

```
echo "Total number of users: " . sizeof($export);
```

Check out `w3schools.com` fro more info:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sizeof.asp

Also if db is a variable, the it should be $db not simply db

Comment: db::get($data) is static class function

Comment: Okay my mistake, should be Db if you want to follow best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is `db::get($data)` function but if it's return an array, you can count number of items with `sizeof` function:

```
sizeof($export);
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php